# How to stop a Python script without error messages on the shell?

Tags: python, error-handling

I want to stop a Python script on seeing an error message.
I dont want any error message on shell like exit().
How to do it ???

Comment: Could you please provide some code or at least a better description of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Since `sys.exit(0)` does not produce an error message, I'll assume you're not talking about Python.

Comment: @S. Lott I think he means "I don't want any error message on shell, but a clean exit as sys.exit() does".

Answer (score 9):

When you send <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> to a Python script, it raises the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, so you can do something like

```
try:
    ... Work goes here ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: I think he actually meant to ask how to suppress the error message/traceback at ANY error, so the 3rd line would be `except:` instead of `except KeyboardInterrupt:`

Comment: @Rod: I would certainly hope not, as that would make the program impossible to debug.

Comment: @Rod: A bare except should never be used unless the error is raised again, because it hides real errors.